# Exclude input from disabled copy and paste jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code to disable selecting text, copying and paste but it also prevents copying from input/textarea.

```
$('body').bind('cut copy paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

How do I enable copy/paste event listeners from textarea/inputs elements?

Comment: So you want to enable copy paste for textarea/inputs?

Comment: Yes, users should be able to copy from textarea and input but not text on the page.

Comment: Just use `user-select: none;` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect only using CSS. 
Instead of disabling copy and paste using Javascript which will affect the user, you can use css attribute `user-select`

```css
body {
  user-select: none;  //Disables selecting text
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque cumque dolores ad eaque consectetur. Officia quaerat voluptatem laudantium nostrum, debitis modi omnis? Vero laudantium quos assumenda, hic voluptatibus quis illum.</p>
<input type="text" />
```

`user-select` is supported in all modern browsers except Opera Mini and UC Browser. https://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none